# Change the name of a property at runtime of struct

Tags: ios, swift, struct

The JSON Data from API contains price for bitcoin in various currencies. I need to modify my struct at runtime, so that it matches up with the keys in data.

Init, Type alias, and Generics Don't work!

'''

```
struct Model {
    var content : intel  
}

struct intel {
    let last : Float
    let averages : day
    let timestamp : Int64
    let bid : Float
    let ask : Float
}

struct day {
    let day : Float
}
//Intend to change literal value of content at runtime
//Sample Data!

{
    "BTCEUR": {
        "last": 9477.207190353169,
        "averages": {
            "day": 8913.97014278919
        },
        "timestamp": 1561195263,
        "bid": 9473.843088382904,
        "ask": 9477.676160131046
    },
    "BTCUSD": {
        "last": 10791.221908483476,
        "averages": {
            "day": 10149.89204777
        },
        "timestamp": 1561195263,
        "bid": 10787.391373795912,
        "ask": 10791.755900918146
    }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to change the name of a property at runtime is the wrong way to solve this problem. A much better solution is to just decode your JSON into a dictionary.

We can create a typealias like this:

```
typealias BitcoinData = [String: intel]
```

and decode the data like this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let bitcoinData = try! decoder.decode(BitcoinData.self, from: data)
print(bitcoinData["BTCUSD"]!.averages.day) // 10149.892
```

Note how we access `BTCUSD` using the subscript syntax.

In fact, your JSON structure is quite awkward to decode. As you can see, we had to decode to a dictionary here. It would be much better if you could change the JSON structure.